# How to bind selected values of <a4j:repeat><rich:select> to the model?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have the below form:

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:repeat var="drillDownSet" value="#{drilldownRequest.itemDetailMap.entrySet().toArray()}">
        <rich:select>
            <f:selectItems value="#{drillDownSet.value}" var="val"
                itemValue="#{drillDownSet.key}" itemLabel="#{val}" />
        </rich:select>
    </a4j:repeat>
    <h:commandButton value="Summit" action="#{drilldownRequest.itemSpecSummit}" />
</h:form>
```

And the below backing bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class DrillDownRequest {

    Map<String, ArrayList> itemDetailMap;

    public void itemSpecSummit() {
        // How can I retrieve all the selected values from the dropdown menus here?
    }

}
```

How can I retrieve all selected values of the `<rich:select>` in the action method?

Comment: Are you sure the `<f:selectItems>` are correct? Right now all available options have exactly the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `<f:selectItems itemValue>` is broken. It's the **same** for all options. This isn't right. Provided that the `ArrayList` is *actually* a `List<String>`, just this should do:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{drillDownSet.value}" />
```

#### See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info

---

Coming back to the concrete question, and continuing with the above fix, you just need to bind the `<rich:select value>` to another `Map<String, String>` using `#{drillDownSet.key}` as map key and the `<f:selectItems itemValue>` as map value.

```
private Map<String, String> selectedItems = new HashMap<>(); // +getter (setter not necessary)
```

```html
<a4j:repeat var="drillDownSet" value="#{drilldownRequest.itemDetailMap.entrySet().toArray()}">
    <rich:select value="#{drilldownRequest.selectedItems[drillDownSet.key]}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{drillDownSet.value}" />
    </rich:select>
</a4j:repeat>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I did some changes as requested.